# Spotify API Client Credentials returns "error": "invalid_client"

Tags: node.js, api, express, spotify

I'm getting an error back on my server.

{
"error": "invalid_client"
}

I've encoded to base64 and whitelisted the domain, still getting the same error. I would appreciate any help, this is driving me crazy lol.

```
import express from 'express'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

const app = express()

const client_id = "";
const client_secret = "";
const payload = client_id + ":" + client_secret;
const encodedPayload = Buffer.from(payload).toString("base64");

const options = {
  method: "POST",
  body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Basic" + encodedPayload
  },
  json: true
};

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const data = await getToken();
    console.log(data);
    res.json(data);
})


async function getToken(){
  const res = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", options)
  const data = await res.json()
  return data;
}

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: There is currently no spacing between "Basic" and the payload in the "Authorization" header, maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Yes!!! That was it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The solution was mentioned in a comment by [rob_med](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5678408/rob-med):

> There is currently no spacing between "Basic" and the payload in the "Authorization" header

Answer (score 0):

Add space inside string after Basic,

error -"Authorization": **"Basic"** + encodedPayload

solution -"Authorization": **"Basic "** + encodedPayload

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Authorization` header in `grant_type:client_credentials`.

There are 4 types of [grant_types](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/authorization).

In this case need `client_id` and `client_secret` as `query parameters` not as `Authorization header`(it's needed in other type of grants).
So you can do this:

```
    import express from 'express'
    import fetch from 'node-fetch'
    
    const app = express()
    
    const client_id = "";
    const client_secret = "";
    
    
    app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        client_id: clientId,
        client_secret: clientSecret,
    });
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          },
          json: true
        };
      const data = await getToken(queryParams,options);
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    })
    
    
    async function getToken(queryParams,options){
      const res = await fetch(`https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?${queryParams}, options)
      const data = await res.json()
      return data;
    }
    
    app.listen(3000)
```